# How can I send notifications to Chrome when the website tab is closed?

Tags: javascript, notifications

I'm trying to understand how to send notifications using the browser when my website is closed.

I see that Facebook does it but I can't get how.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking for the [Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Push_API):

> The Push API gives web applications the ability to receive messages pushed to them from a server, **whether or not the web app is in the foreground, or even currently loaded, on a user agent**. This lets developers deliver asynchronous notifications and updates to users that opt in, resulting in better engagement with timely new content.

And the [Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification):

> The Notification interface of the Notifications API is used to configure and display desktop notifications to the user.

You must use these in combination with a [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker_API). From the Push API documentation:

> For an app to receive push messages, it has to have an active [service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker_API). When the service worker is active, it can subscribe to push notifications using [PushManager.subscribe()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushManager/subscribe).

Comment: Additional resource: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Roost](http://docs-api.goroost.com/docs/getting-started). Roost is a push notification platform for websites. You can see its documentation to perform both client-side and server-side integrations, so that you can customize your Roost notifications as needed.

Comment: Thanks it seems easy to use! But I need a self-hosted solution. Thanks anyway